# Convert iOS application to 64bit

Tags: ios, xcode, arm64

I'm try to convert my `iPhone` application to `64bit`, because the apple announce that apps can be uploaded only with `64bit` support from February.

From what i read i need to add `arm64` to this values(In the targets):

```
Architecture
Valid Architecture
```

The problem not is that when i add the `arm64` and `build` the application so i get `build failed` message. But there is no error message in the `Issue Navigator`.

Any idea why it happen?

Comment: Look at the error message in the build log (shown via the Report navigator).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There will be an error in the Report Navigator. In the left hand panel in Xcode it is the right hand button, highlighted blue in the attached screen shot. You may need to scroll up the list to see the error.
[image]